# Cambiar tipo de gráfico en tiempo real

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Buenas a todos me gustaría cambiar el type de un gráfico chart.js en tiempo real mandándole el valor desde un select, el valor ya lo tengo capturado de hecho de igual menera consigo cambiarle la leyenda de posición, el problema viene cuando intento cambiar el formato del gráfico, ejemplo de line a pie, paso el código:

```
                                $("#edit_type").change(function() {
                                      dato= $("#edit_type").val();
                                      if(dato=="graph/pie"){
                                          dato="pie";
                                      }else if(dato=="line_graph"){
                                          dato="line";
                                      }else if(dato=="bar_graph"){
                                          dato="bar";
                                      }else{
                                          dato="pie";
                                      }
                                      //window.myPie.clear();
                                      //window.myPie.reset();
                                      //window.myPie.destroy();
                                      //window.myPie.reset();
                                      config.type = dato; 
                                      window.myPie.update();
                                      window.myPie.render();
                                      console.log(dato);
                                      });          
                         /* Fin cambio de grafica */    

                            var config = {
                                    type: dato,
                                    data: {
                                            datasets: [{
                                                    data: [
                                                            randomScalingFactor(),
                                                            randomScalingFactor(),
                                                            randomScalingFactor(),
                                                            randomScalingFactor(),
                                                            randomScalingFactor(),
                                                    ],
                                                    backgroundColor: [
                                                            window.chartColors.red,
                                                            window.chartColors.orange,
                                                            window.chartColors.yellow,
                                                            window.chartColors.green,
                                                            window.chartColors.blue,
                                                    ],
                                                    label: 'Dataset 1',
                                            }],
                                            labels: [
                                                    'Red',
                                                    'Orange',
                                                    'Yellow',
                                                    'Green',
                                                    'Blue'
                                            ]
                                    },
                                    options: {
                                     maintainAspectRatio: false,   
                                    legend: {
                                     position: pos
                                    },
                                            responsive: true
                                    }

                            };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con este código puedes cambiar rápidamente de un gráfico de tipo pie a un gráfico de tipo bar, mandando el tipo de gráfico mediante una variable.
Pregunta resuelta:

```
 config.type=dato;
 window.myPie.destroy();
 var ctx = document.getElementById('chart-area').getContext('2d');
 window.myPie = new Chart(ctx,config)
```

Comment: Exelenteee muchas gracias por la contribución!